# Index of a map in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

There i a way to get the index of a map searching in a specific position in Dart?

i.e.
var foo = [{"Name":"Jhon","Surname":"Doe"},{"Name":"Peter","Surname":"Doe2"}];

I need to find the index of Peter's map, there is a way to get foo.someFunction(..) = 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexWhere()`

Returns the first index in the list that satisfies the provided test.

```
var foo = [{"Name":"Jhon","Surname":"Doe"},{"Name":"Peter","Surname":"Doe2"}];
var name = "Peter";
print(foo.indexWhere((person) => person['Name'] == name)); // this prints 1
```

You can read more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get the index of an element in an array. Your model class will look like this:

```
class NewModel {
  String name;
  String surName;

  NewModel({this.name, this.surName});

  NewModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['Name'];
    surName = json['SurName'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Name'] = this.name;
    data['SurName'] = this.surName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
List<NewModel> myList; // Your list with values... 

final List uniqueList = Set.from(myList).toList();


uniqueList.map((val) {
    String idx = uniqueList.indexOf(val);

    return something;
}
```

You can read more from [here](https://fireship.io/snippets/dart-how-to-get-the-index-on-array-loop-map/).